# Applying jQuery only to some input fields, not all of the same type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('input[type=password]').getAttribute("id") == "password_form") {
        $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
            var pswd = $(this).val();
            //validate length
            if(pswd.length < 8) {
                $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            } else {
                $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            }
            //validate letter
            if ( pswd.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
                $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }
            //validate capital letter
            if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
                $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }
            //validate number
            if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
                $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }
        }).focus(function() {
            $('#password_info').show();
        }).blur(function() {
            $('#password_info').hide();
        });
    } else {
        var pswd = $(this).val();
        var pswd2 = $(document).getElementById("password_form").val();
        $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
            if(pswd != pswd2) {
                $('same').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            } else {
                $('same').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            }
        }).focus(function() {
            $('#password_info_re-enter').show();
        }).blur(function() {
            $('#password_info_re-enter').hide();
        });
    }
});
```

I have two password fields since one is the first one you write your password in and the second one is for verification in a sign-up form. But I want to show password requirements on the first password box but a different box on the verification box showing whether the password matches or not.

So to do this I tried to see if I could find the ID of one of them so that the first part only applied to the first one and not the second one.

How would I do this?

Comment: You do that already `$('input[type=password]').getAttribute("id") == "password_form"` what is the question ?

Comment: just select the first one: `$('input[type=password]:eq(0)')`

Comment: Ah, thanks @JoshuaK. Did not know about that one!

Comment: If you know their IDs why don't you use directly them in your code instead of input type

Comment: `.getAttribute("id")` isn't a jQuery method and will throw error ...use `attr('id')` or `$('input[type=password]')[0].getAttribute("id")` and keep in mind using id as the  selector makes more sense as the generic one will only get value of first matching selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you change the approach to targeting the password elements as a collection using one event handler and moving your business logic inside that handler along the lines of:

```
var $pwds = $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
      // define the values and elements
      var isMainField = this.id === 'password_form',
          $otherField = $pwds.not(this),
          mainPwd = isMainField ? this.value : $otherField.val(),
          secondPwd = isMainField ? $otherField.val() : this.value ;

       // validation stuff
       if( isMainfield){
           // code for main
       }else{
           //code for secondary
       }    
});
```